# Flowing user authentication across an Azure architecture

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

- Users in Azure Active Directory Azure
- App Services for WebSite and Services

I am creating a Web Site that a Manager would authenticate with using an Azure Active Directory account. That website would offer up sales data on the staff they manage.

The service that returns the sales data for staff member A will be being called on behalf of the manager.

My question is what is the correct way to flow the "identity" of the logged in manager through the calls to the various services.

Do I simply protect the services with a System Level authentication at the level of the website and pass the manager's user identifier as a parameter in the request?

OR

Do I try and flow the oauth identity onward to the services so that they are called in the security context of the manager? If using this approach how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if the your business doesn't have a high security requirement, the first option is great. But if you want higher security, you can use second option.

For second option, you need to register an application in your azure ad for your app service. Follow steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-an-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-the-api). And register another application in AD to represent client app by following these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-another-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-a-client-application). Then go to your client app and [grant permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#grant-permissions-in-azure-ad) to allow the client-app to call the backend-app. After that, the manager need to get access token before request the api in your app server to return sales data.

Comment: I may have poorly explained what I see as option 2. What you have described is the WebSite calling the service in the context of the Website (as a registered application). What I meant was that the option 2 call would be in the security context of the logged in  user (The "Manager"). This would allow the service to look at the authentication detail and authorize the Manager to access data they are allowed to see and only that data

Answer (score 0):

This Azure sample shows exactly what we want to acheive [with an ASpNet Core Web Site calling own AspNet Core Service secured with our Active Directooy organisation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg)

I am having some issues getting it to work but this sampple is what I was hoping for from asking this qeuestion. FWIW here is the seperate question covering the specific issue I am having implementing the sample, [Why Http 401 when calling AspNet Core API secured with AAD. Our WebApp, Web API and AD Org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64450218/why-http-401-when-calling-aspnet-core-api-secured-with-aad-our-webapp-web-api)